# Hide Or Add To Magnification Menu

Tags: unix

Is there a way to hide or add to the Magnification menu at the bottom of each notebook.

I understand if it can't be removed but then I would like to add to the menu because it takes up a lot of space.

[image]

Comment: look for `WindowElements` in the documentation. That is an option for notebooks and giving a list without the `"MagnificationPopup"` entry will hide that menu. I think you will also have to remove `"StatusArea"` to really regain that space but I don't have linux available right now to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for a single window.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   WindowElements -> {"MemoryMonitor", "HorizontalScrollBar", 
 "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}]
```

Do ctrl+shift+o and global preferences for multiple windows.